# How do I change the capitalization of month names used by SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, internationalization, simpledateformat, date-formatting, capitalization

This code:

```
Locale brazil = new Locale("pt","BR");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d 'de' MMMM", brazil);
Date date = new Date();
String result = format.format(date);
System.out.println(result);
```

outputs:

```
28 de Junho
```

[The problem is that month names are not capitalized in Brazil.](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_of_Wiktionary_pages#Capitalization_of_month_names)

Is this a bug in the JDK? If so, should I report it? Where?

How do I work around it? Where does Java store the month names it uses in different locales? Can I override or change them? Or do I have to do:

```
format.format(date).toLowerCase();
```

?

Comment: This might be useful: http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/index.jsp & http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/

Comment: Do you control the VM? If you do, trying a newer one may help, otherwise you should implement and of course *comment* measures such as using `toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in the JDK. Try the latest JDK, and if you still have the problem, search [Bug parade](http://bugs.sun.com/), and if you don't find anything already, then file a new report.